# Linux - LVM pvcreate command not working

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm, lvm2

Using fdisk I create a new partition, write it with 'w', reboot Linux
list volumes with lsblk. It shows up fine as /dev/sda3.

But if I do a pvcreate mylvm /dev/sda3

It cant find it. It sayes device not found or ignored by filtering.

I'm trying to get it into my lvm group so that I can extend it using the lvextend command, as my device /dev/sda has more space that I need added to my LVM root.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pvcreate` expects the name of a block device, but above you are giving it two parameters, `mylvm` (which I presume is a logical volume name) *and* the block device `/dev/sda3`.

### Create the physical volume

You've said you need to extend your root logical volume, first, you need to create the new physical volume with `pvcreate /dev/sda3`, `pvdisplay` will list them.

### Add to the volume group

Now, add your new physical volume, `/dev/sda3`, to your volume group. To find what volume group your `root` logical volume is using, run `lvdisplay` and find your root:

```
$ lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgdata
  ...
```

The `VG Name` line is the name of the volume group in use, so that's what needs to be extended - above the volume group is called `vgdata`.

Running `vgextend vgdata /dev/sda3` will extend the `vgdata` volume group using your `/dev/sda3` physical volume.

### Extend the logical volume

Now you need to extend your root logical volume. The `LV Path` line in the above output gives you the path to your logical volume, in this case it is `/dev/vg/root`. You just have to call `lvextend` now:

```
$ lvextend -L +1G /dev/vg/root
```

This will extend by 1 GiB. To use *all* of the free space you added to your volume group, you need to call `lvextend` with `-l +100%FREE` which tells it to use all the extents left in the volume group.

```
$ lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg/root
```

### Resize the filesystem

Finally, you need to grow the filesystem. If using `ext2/3/4` run:

```
$ resize2fs /dev/vg/root
```

If using `xfs` run:

```
$ xfs_growfs /dev/vg/root
```